# Why does my javascript work in codepen but not once published to github?

Tags: javascript, html

Actually none of my Javascript is working. Some of it was for a while, and then it stopped. I got the turnArray function working fine in Codepen but when I take it over to my Github page nothing works anymore.

I'm a beginner with Javascript so I may be missing something obvious but I can't seem to find the answer online without someone more experienced looking over my shoulder at this one.

edit: I have run the chrome debugging and could not figure out what it required me to do. It returns these errors:
"Application Cache Error event: Invalid or missing manifest origin trial token

Uncaught SyntaxError: Malformed arrow function parameter list

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

```js
/* Decide My Day Script */

function turnArray() {
  //assign value of textarea to mytext
  var outfitText = document.getElementById("outfitoptions").value;

  //split mytext by nextline = "\n" 
  var outfitArray = outfitText.split("\n");

  /* add second */

  var mealsText = document.getElementById("mealoptions").value;

  var mealsArray = mealsText.split("\n");

  /* add third */

  var tasksText = document.getElementById("taskoptions").value;

  var tasksArray = tasksText.split("\n");

  /* start picking random */

  const randomOutfit = outfitArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * outfitArray.length)];

  const randomMeal = mealsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * mealsArray.length)];

  const randomTask = tasksArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * tasksArray.length)];

  /* get result */

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Today you will wear ' + randomOutfit + '. ' + 'Plan on eating ' + randomMeal + ' later.' + ' Your assigned task to accomplish is ' + randomTask + ' so make sure you plan accordingly!';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" manifest="app.appcache">

</html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/41f205b4ea.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



  <title>Decide My Day</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="textbox">

    <textarea id="outfitoptions" placeholder="Placeholder text" style="height:100px"></textarea>

    <textarea id="mealoptions" name="mealoptions" placeholder="Placeholder text" style="height:100px"></textarea>

    <textarea id="taskoptions" name="taskoptions" placeholder="Placeholder text" style="height:100px"></textarea>

    <br>

    <button onclick="turnArray()"> Decide My Day! </button>

    <p id="result"></p>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: as you can see, the code you provided is not the cause of those errors. So, you have other code involved that is not shared here.

Comment: Those error messages come with file names and line numbers that tell where the errors are.

Comment: This is non-reproducible.

Comment: @RandyCasburn thank you for your response. I am trying to figure out what relevant code I haven't included here

Comment: provide a link to your codepen.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Okay, I looked into the line number the error message was giving and found the site was loading an old version of the javascript? I clicked 'disable cache' on the f12 panel and it appears to be loading the new version, which I made sure matched what I uploaded here exactly, and it is working like it is supposed to. thank you so much!

Comment: @GuyIncognito thank you, this helped me find the error!

Comment: If you get your code to work in chrome on your computer, and it doesn't work on codepen, github, here in snippet = report the issue to them = they are not running full true javascript....